# reading .xls files with xlrd

Tags: python

When reading data from excel tables with an xlrd package, the output often has a prefix u' or something similiar (like, in one case, it had a \u2013 instead of a '-' character). Why is this and which are the characters i need to look out for, as I'm going to have to parse some information from the spreadsheet cells.

Here's an example:

```
>>> wb = xlrd.open_workbook('tellimusleht.xls')
>>> sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0).row_values(5)
[2.0, u'aken sisseavanev, pakett, aluliist, ilma petekata parem', 552.0, 1729.0, 2.0, u'Sp.Barbados 4*6 \u2013 1 maja ']
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `u` denotes a [unicode string](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). `\u2013` is the [Unicode EN DASH character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm), which is displayed as `–`, but it isn't the same as a regular dash:

```
–
-  # Notice how one is longer than the other
```